# Cant get my checkbox value in a variable using state in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

The code for use state and handling inputs is given below. I can't get my game name in console on selecting, why?

```
const [tour, setTour] = useState({
        cafename: "", contactno: "", state: "", address: "", game: "", date: "", prizepool: ""
    });

    var name, value;
    const handleInputs = (e) => {
        console.log(e);

        name = e.target.name;
        value = e.target.value;

        setTour({ ...user, [name]: value });
    }
```

The select code is given below.

```
<div className="form-group">
                                <label for="games">Games</label>
                                <select class="custom-select" name= "game" value={tour.game} onChange={handleInputs}>
                                    <option selected>Select game</option>
                                    <option value="leagueoflegends">LEAGUE OF LEGENDS</option>
                                    <option value="valorant">VALORANT</option>
                                    <option value="rainbow6">RAINBOW 6 SIEGE</option>
                                    <option value="dota2">DOTA 2</option>
                                    <option value="cs">CS GO </option>

                                    placeholder="Enter games"
                                </select>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CheckBox has checked property for value:

```
const handleInputs = (e) => {
    name = e.target.name;
    value = e.target.type === 'checkbox' ? e.target.checked : e.target.value;

    setTour(state => { ...state, [name]: value });
}
```

Comment: Is my checkbox code right?

Comment: What checkbox? You just have a select in html code.

Comment: Sorry,  Is my select code right?

Comment: Yes. Your select code is correct. 
But change the setTour:

setTour(state => { ...state, [name]: value });